# What is the difference between 'and' or '&' in kdb?

Tags: kdb

What is the point for having `and` if `&` does the same thing? 
Should I prefer one over the other ? and why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`and` and `&` are synonyms, you can use them interchangeably.

```
q)and
&
```

However, as a matter of coding style you may want to use `and` whenever both left and right arguments are boolean to help readers of your code.

The same applies to `or` and `|`.

Please note that in q/k `and` (and its synonym `&`) is not a bitwise operator and it's not a boolean operator either! It returns the lesser of two values: see https://code.kx.com/q/ref/lesser.

Comment: Similar considerations apply to the aggregator pairs `max`/`any` and `min`/`all`.